# How to make smooth scrolling to the next target element while scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, click, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to reach similar solution of scrolling to the next target element like here: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page3

My code sofar:

```
let disableClick = false
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  window.onscroll = slideMenu;
  if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.offsetTop) {
    const scrolledPx = (window.scrollY - elementTarget.offsetTop);

    if (scrolledPx > 100 && !disableClick) {          
      const link = document.getElementById('2');          
      link.click();
      disableClick = true
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I scroll to the next element and go back up, the smooth scroll is disabled. How can I enable click event when I have condition like this or similar?:

```
if (scrolledPx < 100 && !disableClick) {          
  const link = document.getElementById('2');          
  link.click();
  disableClick = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css for a smooth scrolling

```
 html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
```